# How to calculate number (max value) in percentage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have set max value to 3MB in bytes now i want to set `$scope.dynamic` value percentage of max value, Below code is returning dynamic value is NaN.
How can i calculate dynamic value percentage of max value and make 3MB as 100% to display in progressbar ?

ctrl.js

```
     var maxBytes = 1000 * 1000 * 3;
        $scope.max = maxByte;
        $scope.random = function(value) {
            $scope.dynamic = parseFloat(value/Math.pow(maxBytes)).toFixed(1);
            console.log('current value-dynamic',$scope.dynamic);
        };

$scope.random(1024)// bytes
```

main.html

```
<uib-progress type="info" value="((dynamic / max) * 100)"></></uib-progress>
```

Comment: I am not sure why this question is being down voted , can i get some comment ?

Comment: Some basic debugging, plz. Use a debugger or print out the values of each variable. What is `Math.pow(maxBytes)` supposed to do?

Comment: i spent some time i could not resolve the problem i kept getting same error so i thought of posting on SO to get some help

Comment: If you want help, you'll need to clarify the question when asked to do so. What is `Math.pow(maxBytes)` supposed to do? `Math.pow()` requires two parameters but you only use one.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this should solve your problem

```
<uib-progress type="info" value="{{((dynamic / max) * 100)}}"></></uib-progress>
```

Comment: i did not get this answer i dont have variable `bar`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with different approach.

```
$scope.random = function(value) {
        $scope.dynamic = value;
        $scope.downloadMessage = parseFloat((value/maxBytes) * 100).toFixed(0);
}
```